# Why does short-format apply to indefinite articles and how to avoid that?

Tags: acro

I would like to use the `acro` package's `short-format` property to print an acronym's short form using small caps.  Unfortunately, when I use the acronym's `\iac` command, the indefinite article is also included with the format given by `short-format`.  This seems especially unusual since plural endings are not affected by `short-format` (just as I would expect).

How can I get the short form, but *not* its indefinite article, to appear as specified by `short-format`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{use-id-as-short}

\DeclareAcronym{LTS}{
  short-indefinite = an,
  short-format = \scshape\MakeLowercase,
  long = labeled transition system,
}

\begin{document}
\Iac{LTS} is useful.  Here is \iac{LTS} to use.
\Acp{LTS} are interesting.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see an option. Open an issue at https://github.com/cgnieder/acro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug. This is fixed in `acro` v3.3 and greater. The MWE now gives this:

[image]